# Saving BufferedImage using zip compression

Tags: java, zip, bufferedimage

How would I go about saving a BufferedImage straight to a zip file.

Here is my current code for saving my BufferedImage to a zip file but I do not know how to convert the BufferedImage to a InputStream so that it can be saved to the zip file.

If possible I need to save the BufferedImage straight from RAM without saving it to HDD first

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
try
{

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(PathName + imageData.getFileNumber() + ".zip");
    ZipOutputStream zipOutputStream = new ZipOutputStream(outputStream);
    ZipEntry imageZipOutput = new ZipEntry(imageData.getFileNumber() + ".png");
    zipOutputStream.putNextEntry(imageZipOutput);

    //the BufferedImage is stored in imageData.getImage();
    //how would I parse the BufferedImage to the InputStream below without saving the png first but straight from RAM
    InputStream in = new InputStream();

    int len;
    while ((len = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
    {
        zipOutputStream.write(buffer, 0, len);
    }

    in.close();
    zipOutputStream.closeEntry();

    zipOutputStream.close();

}
```

Comment: ROM = Read Only Memory. I don't think you meant that.

Comment: oops I was supposed to say HDD edited OP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `ImageIO.write(RenderedImage im,String formatName, OutputStream output)` to write the output. Pass a `ZipOutputStream` for the OutputStream parameter.

Check [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.OutputStream%29) page for more info.

Comment: Seems you where two seconds faster. Darn :D